# Preposition the camera on the first person controller in unity

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine

So i am making a multiplayer game in unity and i want for players to be able to have a first person experience while other players can see a body walking around rather than a floating blob that is the default first person controller. So i take the scripts from the first person controller and i put them inside the third person controller. Except the camera is in the lower torso rather than the head, where i want it to be. Does anyone know how i can move it into the head? Preferably so that i don't see the inside of the head XD

Answer (score 0):

If you open the hierarchy of your new "Fake first person controller", you may see plenty of child objects. Somewhere, you will find the camera.

Just take it now and bring it at desired heigth!

*I don't know how much changed in the charcontrollers since unity 3.x, but I'm pretty sure the philosophy will be pretty the same.